# Combining Multiple Sets of Letters in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to print all the combinations there are for multiple sets of letters without repetition.

An example: A,B,C and X,Y,Z

The combinations would be:

AX
AY
AZ
BX
BY
BZ
CX
CY
CZ

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get what you want.

```
from itertools import product
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']

for i in product(a, b):
    print ''.join(i)
```

Comment: That's the one.  The itertools solutions are great for raking in the reputation too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over both sets:

```
for a in abcstring:
    for x in xyzstring:
        print a + x
```